# local log filtering and analytics

Tags: osx, data-analysis, logs, log-analysis

There is a vast amount of log analytics tools available like kibana, datadog and what not.
I'm searching for a free tool (license must allow commercial use) that allows to just drop in a log file, of any format at best. In my case mostly server, elb logs.

Then I want to filter and analyze them. For example check which requests logged in an elb log took more than x seconds. Or filter all 5xx errors from the log.

I'm using a Mac.